# Do i need to ask gcloud support for enabling exchange custom rules in VPC peering?

Tags: exchange-server, gcloud

I have created two gcloud projects, one for cloud sql and one for kubernete cluster. For accessing SQL in project one i have set import export custom routes . Do i need to take gcloud confirmation for this or this is enough? as i have read somewhere that after these steps ask gcloud support for enable the exchange of custom routes for your speckle-umbrella VPC network associated with your instance that is automatically created upon the Cloud SQL instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this step is not included in the public documentation and is not necessary if you are connecting from within the same project or from any service project ( if configured with Shared VPC), then you don't require to export those routes. This is generally required if you are connecting from on-prem.

If you are having anny issue please let us know